# Proguard - do not obfuscate Kotlin data classes

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, data-class

In my project I use [AutoValue](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2016/03/22/autovalue/) for my old model classes. I started using Kotlin and I want to use [Data Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) instead of AutoValue. I want to disable the obfuscation for all **Data classes** in my **Data layer** but to keep obfuscating the other classes in the package.

Is there a way to do this?

I would expect to have something like this in my **Proguard** file:

```
-keepclassmembers data class example.data_layer.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

To fix the problem I moved the model classes to **model package** and added new [ProGuard](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/introduction.html) rule for the package.

```
-keep class com.company.myfeature.model.** { *; }
```

Another solution would be to use [@Keep annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep) from support library to disable the obfuscation for the class:

```
@Keep
data class MyRequestBody(val value: String)
```

Using [@Keep](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep) may cause problems because it's easy to forget to add it for new classes.

Hopefully in future there will be a way with one **ProGuard rule** to disable the obfuscation for all **Data classes** in package without the need to have a sub-package for the **model classes**.

Comment: I wouldn't want no obfuscation on all `data class`es

Comment: If you use `@Keep` and have nested data classes, don't forget to add `@Keep` to each of them.

Comment: as you mentioned writing keep with a package [-keep class com.company.myfeature.model.** { *; } ] that is only work in Java, It's not working in Kotlin. can you please help me, Thanks

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Proguard works the same way for Java and Kotlin. You need Proguard help - search for other questions with your problem.

Answer (score 4):

While `@Keep` annotation works, another option is to add `@SerializedName` to the properties:

```
data class SomeDataClass(
    @SerializedName("prop1") val PropertyOne: String, 
    @SerializedName("prop2") val PropertyTwo: Boolean
)
```

Comment: Could you give an explanation of what @SerializedName does and how it fixes the issue?

Comment: This will not work. either @Keep will work or proguard rule needs to be added for telling proguard not to obfuscate data class

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure keeping whole data class is good or not. but if it's requirement, the below proguard rule will work.
but, this is just workaround. I suggest without confidence. please consider carefully.

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class example.data_layer.** {
    public ** component1();
    <fields>;
}
```

I have an article here with a more detailed explanation: [How to make Proguard keep Kotlin data class](https://medium.com/@dss99911/kotlin-proguard-keep-data-class-ca2660cf2d03)

Comment: Your profile indicates you're associated with the article you have linked. Linking to something you're affiliated with *without disclosing it's yours* is considered spammy on Stack Overflow. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion). I've edited your post to resolve this issue, and hope you can take into consideration in future.

Comment: @SamuelLiew
Oh.. I didn't know that. I'll definitely follow your teaching in the future. Thanks for your teaching

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem with @Keep annotaion
for all model classes that parse api responce data

@Keep

data class MyClass()