# How do i avoid Obfuscating Firebase Model Fields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate my android app but when i do generate apk as a release and run on the device then my firebase field names are get changed. And also some fields data is not uploaded to the firebase real time database for example System.currentTimeMillisecond(), passwd.

My application works fine without obfuscation and inserts all data properly. After obfuscation it behaves incorrectly and doesn't insert some data properly into firebase.

**Expected node:**

```
-userid
 -name:"abc"
 -age:15
 -passwd:"pass@123"
 -timestamp:16003243241
```

**After obfuscate:**

```
-userid
 -a:"abc"
 -b:15
```

**My UserModel class**

```
public class UserModel{
    
    public int age;
    public String name,passwd;
    public long timestamp;

    public UserModel(){}
    public UserModel(String name, String passwd, int age, long timestamp){
        this.name=name;
        this.passwd=passwd;
        this.age=age;
        this.timestamp=timestamp;
    }
}
```

**I have applied into build.gradle: app**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources=true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

**Proguard:**

```
-keep class yourpackage.** { *; }
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
```

I have min sdk 23 and target 28. Please help me obfuscate data properly.

Comment: Are you using GSON for serialization/deserialization

Comment: Add your code for data model class too

Comment: Try adding the rule in proguard rules `-keep class com.yourpackage.UserModel` replace `yourpackage` with the right package name for the model class

Comment: Where is `UserModel` located? Ar you sure you are using the correct package name?

Comment: @AlexMamo it is inside the subpackage (named firebase) of main app package (com.myapp). Full path is : com.myapp.firebase.UserModel.java

Comment: In that case, you should use `-keepclassmembers com.myapp.firebase.UserModel** { *; }`. For more info, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719791/firebase-firestore-variable-name-changed/60719948#60719948) out. Does it work this way?

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please correct my rules / gradle and rewrite answer. I have other 2 firebase models too. How do i write this rule for MathModel, BookModel on the same package? Should i keep old rules?

Comment: Show us the global rules in your Proguard file.

Comment: @AlexMamo try to answer questions instead of comment. This website threatening me block account by showing "no answers from long. account at risk " :(

Comment: @kattie Check the link in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

you figured out the problem obfuscation changes your model you can ignore those changes
take look at this solution thanks to Mario Kutlev and Danish Ansari
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156695/9077875

> To fix the problem I moved the model classes to model package and added new >ProGuard rule for the package.
>
> `-keep class com.company.myfeature.model.** { *; }`
>
> Another solution would be to use @Keep annotation from support library to >disable the obfuscation for the class:
>
> `@Keep`
> `data class MyRequestBody(val value: String)`
>
> Using @Keep may cause problems because it's easy to forget to add it for new >classes.
>
> Hopefully in future there will be a way with one ProGuard rule to disable the >obfuscation for all Data classes in package without the need to have a sub->package for the model classes.