# Kotlin automatically changes parameter names in release build

Tags: android, kotlin, release, field-names

Json object's field name automatically changing in release build and causing api to fail.

Data Object :

`data class SleepStage(val awake:Double, val light: Double, val rem:Double, val deep:Double)`

IN DEBUG MODE

```
SleepStage": {"awake": 0.58,"light": 4.23,"rem": 1.28,"deep": 0.35 }
```

IN RELEASE MODE:

```
SleepStage": {"a": 0.58,"b": 4.23,"c": 1.28,"d": 0.35 }
```

Comment: This "MAY" be of assistance, the Proguard obfuscation of the class when building might be causing the name change. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098682/proguard-do-not-obfuscate-kotlin-data-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called obfuscation. When you create a release version, Proguard shortens all variable names.

Check out this StackOverflow post:
[Proguard - do not obfuscate Kotlin data classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098682/proguard-do-not-obfuscate-kotlin-data-classes)

It should be enough to add a `@Keep` annotation to your class:

```
@Keep
data class SleepStage(
    ...
)
```