# In internal testing, application crashed on start with Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics, stack-trace

my app is working perfectly in debug mode but when I upload my app in internal testing, app crashes on start everytime. Here's the crash report:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class e.g.b.c.i.f.f2: void e.g.b.c.i.f.f2.run() failed to verify: void e.g.b.c.i.f.f2.run(): [0x36] cannot access instance field e.g.b.c.i.f.f0 e.g.b.c.i.f.j.b from object of type Reference: java.lang.Object (declaration of 'e.g.b.c.i.f.f2' appears in /data/app/~~sg8-kWQGjjoS5OEELCEY7A==/com.example.myapp-nbqfHplywzk3pMiZRRiUsw==/base.apk)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.zzx.zzb(zzx.java:9)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.consent_sdk.zzw.run(zzw.java:9)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

I've provided the problem and looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because the proguard obfuscate your code. Idealy in the release env, the code needs to be obfuscated to prevent a reverse enginering in your release apk. you can see in the `app/build.gradle` there's `minifyEnabled true` to obfuscate your code. Here is the [reference](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code) to read.

You can try some scenario :

1. try to set minifyEnable to `false` then build your release apk. Observe the whether the issue is still happen.
2. if it doesn't error after you set minifyEnable to `false`, try to modify your `proguard-rules.pro` and set your data classes to not being obfuscated. Here's the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098682/proguard-do-not-obfuscate-kotlin-data-classes) for doing that and don't forget to set `minifyEnabled true` again.

I hope it help.